# Desplegar elementos de forma similar a como Materialize lo hace

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

Quisiera agregar un efecto a un botón en mi html, que al posicionar el cursor se desplieguen otros dos botones hacia arriba con su animación (tipo adjuntar archivos como en Whatsapp Web) y cuando retire el cursor, se vuelvan a esconder.

Sé que con las funciones de jQuery `mouseenter()` y `mouseleave()` se puede lograr. También se puede lograr con Materialize (ejemplo abajo). ¿Cómo se podría hacer **SÓLO con JS y el CSS**?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
    <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola Candelo, por favor comparte lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. También añade algo más de información: ¿quieres usar jQuery o no? ¿quieres usar JavaScript o sólo con CSS? ¿Con qué dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro , Gracias por tu gesto.
En la descripción y en las etiquetas, creo que se puede ver muy claro que deseo usar jQuery, (ojalá todo fuera con jQuery); lo que deseo es sencillamente hacer el mismo botón con los mismos efectos que puse como ejemplo.
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acá te muestro una propuesta utilizando elementos fijos y únicamente CSS
las clases clave acá son

- `button-radio--main` El botón principal
- `button-radio--hidden` Los botones auxiliares que estarán escondidos

Dada la estructura que te propongo los elementos dentro de `button__container`, el botón principal deberá ubicarse de últimas al interior de este contenedor, por lo demás funciona bien sin ninguna ayuda de Javascript/jQuery adicional.

```css
.button__container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 40px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
          flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.button-radio {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.button-radio--red {
  background: #ff1f1f;
}

.button-radio--blue {
  background: #03a1fc;
}

.button-radio--yellow {
  background: #ffd21f;
}

.button-radio--hidden {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.button__container:hover > .button-radio--hidden {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="button__container">
    <div class="button-radio button-radio--hidden button-radio--yellow">A</div>
    <div class="button-radio button-radio--hidden button-radio--blue">B</div>
    <div class="button-radio button-radio--main button-radio--red">C</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mil, y mil, y mil Gracias hermano, de verdad, muchas gracias.

Comment: Con todo gusto :)

Comment: Hola Daniel, ¿qué tal?
Bro, estoy intentando hacer el mismo efecto, pero en vez de que se desplacen los otros botones de manera vertical se desplacen de manera horizontal.. Ya intenté con un `transform: translateX();`, y no lo he conseguido.. ¿podrías ayudarme por favor? Muchas gracias crack!